# Bad Subscript in BBC Basic

Tags: arrays, file, basic

I'm trying to create an array in BBC Basic which stores film names and relevant data to a file, and you can then search through that data using the film names.
Although my data is being saved to a file, i'm having trouble opening it up again in order to print it onto the screen, can anybody help? When i try to run the program it comes up with a subscript error in line 105. Thanks.

```html
   15 REM -------------------------------------------------------
   20 INPUT "How many movies would you like to add";AmountMovies
   25 X = OPENOUT("Film Directory")
   30 DIM Film$(AmountMovies,2)
   35 FOR N% = 1 TO AmountMovies
   40   PRINT "The film name was:"
   45   INPUT Film$(N%,0)
   50   PRINT "The director was:"
   55   INPUT Film$(N%,1)
   60   PRINT "The plotline is:"
   65   INPUT Film$(N%,2)
   70   PRINT ""
   75   PRINT#X, Film$(N%,0), Film$(N%,1), Film$(N%,2)
   80 NEXT N%
   85 CLOSE#X
   90 REM -------------------------------------------------------
   95 X = OPENIN("Film Directory")
  100 INPUT "What movie do you wish to search for";WhichMovie
  105 INPUT#X, Film$(N%,0), Film$(N%,1), Film$(N%,2)
  110 IF WhichMovie == Film$(N%,0) THEN
  115   PRINT "The film name is:"Film$(N%,0)
  120   PRINT "The director was:"Film$(N%,1)
  125   PRINT "The film is about:"Film$(N%,2)
  130 ENDIF
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason this is failing is because you're using N% at line 105. In this particular case, N% is always 1 higher than 'AmountMovies' as that is the way it is left when you leave the FOR...NEXT loop. As you have DIMmed only 'AmountMovies' you will get the error as its trying to access AmountMovies+1.

There is a more fundemental problem with this code though.

If you look at the PRINT# (line 75) part of it, you'll notice it is encased in a FOR...NEXT loop.

The second part of your program should probably look like this:

```
 90 REM -------------------------------------------------------
 95 X = OPENIN("Film Directory")
100 INPUT "What movie do you wish to search for";WhichMovie
105 FOR N% = 1 TO AmountMovies
110  INPUT#X, Film$(N%,0), Film$(N%,1), Film$(N%,2)
115  IF WhichMovie = Film$(N%,0) THEN
120   PRINT "The film name is:"Film$(N%,0)
125   PRINT "The director was:"Film$(N%,1)  
130   PRINT "The film is about:"Film$(N%,2)
135  ENDIF
140 NEXT N%
145 CLOSE#X
```

This is all done from memory as i've not got access to a BBC BASIC interpreter - so I might be totally wrong with this solution!

Answer (score 1):

An improved version. Note use of linear search.  Also the equality operator is a single '='.

```
 90 REM -------------------------------------------------------
 95 X = OPENIN("Film Directory")
100 INPUT "What movie do you wish to search for";WhichMovie
103 N% = 1 : found% = false
105 WHILE N%<= AmountMovies AND NOT(found%)
110  INPUT#X, Film$(N%,0), Film$(N%,1), Film$(N%,2)
115  IF WhichMovie = Film$(N%,0) THEN
120   found% = true
125  ELSE
130    N% += 1
135  ENDIF
140 ENDWHILE
145 CLOSE#x
148 IF found% THEN
150   PRINT "The film name is:"Film$(N%,0)
155   PRINT "The director was:"Film$(N%,1)  
160   PRINT "The film is about:"Film$(N%,2)
170 ELSE
175   PRINT "Not found."
180 ENDIF
```